# Obtengo filas dobles al hacer un UNION entre 2 tablas con algunos campos comunes en SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner, union

Estoy con una BD en la que tengo 2 tablas. En 1 de ellas tengo los campos fecha, moneda, y ganancia patrimonial. En la segunda, tengo Fecha, moneda y RCM. Necesito hacer una consulta que me dé como resultado 4 columnas: Fecha, Moneda, G.Patrimonial y RCM.
Para ello, he usado dos consultas, una LET JOIN y otra RIGHT JOIN además de UNION para conseguir obtener los registros de ambas. Ambas consultas tienen un GROUP BY Fecha y Moneda.
El problema es que obtengo filas dobles en los resúmenes por año. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT G.AÑO, G.TOKEN, Round(Sum(G.["GANANCIA PATRIMONIAL"]),2) AS GANACIAS_TRADE, Round(Sum(R.RCM),2) AS RCM, Round(GANACIAS_TRADE+RCM,2) AS [GANANCIA NETA]
FROM [GANANCIA y PÉRDIDAS POR MONEDA Y AÑO] AS G LEFT JOIN [RCM POR AÑO] AS R ON G.token = R.MONEDA
GROUP BY G.AÑO, g.token

UNION SELECT R.AÑO, R.MONEDA, Round(Sum(G.["GANANCIA PATRIMONIAL"]),2) AS GANACIAS_TRADE, Round(Sum(R.RCM),2) AS RCM, Round(GANACIAS_TRADE+RCM,2) AS [GANANCIA NETA]
FROM [GANANCIA y PÉRDIDAS POR MONEDA Y AÑO] AS G RIGHT JOIN [RCM POR AÑO] AS R ON G.token = R.MONEDA
GROUP BY R.AÑO, R.MONEDA
HAVING (((R.MONEDA) Is Not Null));
```

Obtengo como resultado la suma para cada moneda, pero hay varios casos en los que obtengo el total para 2021, el total para 2022 y un tercer registro, también con fecha 2022, que me suma ambas, lo cual no me vale. ¿Me podéis echar un cable?. Gracias.

Tras seguir buscando posibilidades, he conseguido un resultado válido. No es muy elegante, porque me pide un valor para la nueva columna en cada tabla, pero el resultado que me da es correcto. ¿Es posible evitar ese diálogo que pide el valor de la nueva columna en cada tabla y que añado directamente 0?.
El código es éste:

```
SELECT F.AÑO, F.TOKEN, ROUND(SUM(F.GANANCIAS),2) AS [RENTAS DEL AHORRO], ROUND(SUM(F.RCM),2) AS RCM
FROM (
SELECT G.AÑO, G.TOKEN, g.GANANCIAS, rcm FROM [GANANCIA y PÉRDIDAS POR MONEDA Y AÑO] AS G 

UNION 

SELECT r.AÑO, r.moneda, ganancias,R.RCM FROM [RCM POR AÑO] AS R) AS F
GROUP BY F.AÑO, F.TOKEN
ORDER BY AÑO
```

Comment: te saldrán dobles en los casos que ON G.token = R.MONEDA

Comment: select distinct * from  (tu consulta)

Comment: HAVING (((R.MONEDA) Is Not Null) and  G.token <> R.MONEDA );

Comment: Gracias Francisco. Efectivamente, he visto que me salen dobles en las monedas que coinciden (INNER JOIN). Si uso:

Comment: Gracias Francisco. Efectivamente, he visto que me salen dobles en las monedas que coinciden (INNER JOIN). Si uso:
Select distinct * from (mi consulta)
sigo obteniendo los registros duplicados.
si pongo:
HAVING (((R.MONEDA) Is Not Null) and G.token <> R.MONEDA )
Obtengo: "Su consulta no incluye la expresión especificada 'Not R.MONEDA Is Null and Not G.Token = R.MONEDA' como parte de una función de agregado.

Comment: He hecho una nueva consulta que une ambas consultas añadiendo la columna que le falta a cada una de ellas. No es muy elegante, porque me pide un valor para la nueva columna en cada tabla, pero el resultado que me da es correcto. Edito mi publicación y la añado.

Comment: que columnas te piden un valor?

Comment: Las que he creado en la nueva consulta. Para la 2ª consulta (RCM POR AÑO) he introducido "GANANCIAS" y para la 1ª "RCM", de forma que cuando lo ejecuto, me pide un valor para esas columnas, puesto que no existen en las consultas.
Al pulsar INTRO, les asigna valor NULL y ya me hace bien la agrupación.
Lo que hago es coger 2 consultas, con 3 campos cada una, le añado 1 campo que le falta a las 2 (el que no tienen de la otra, RCM Y GANANCIAS). De esa forma, obtengo una tabla con 4 columnas y de ahí hago el select con un GROUP BY año y moneda. No sé si me explico

Comment: Ponles un cero directamente en cada una de las select, NO? si entendido bien

Comment: He intentado poner el campo =0 en ambos SELECT, pero me sigue pidiendo el valor y me lo suma/resta al 0. Seguro que existe alguna forma de obtener lo que quiero sin esta chapuza, pero soy bastante nuevo con SQL